# How to wrap text inside a vbox?

Tags: graphics, captions, line-breaking

I am using Ruby's erb templates to generate a LaTeX file that is basically just images with captions (albeit I am not using the `\caption` environment, because it seems to break things). The code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, bindingoffset=1cm, headheight=15pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\normaltitle}{Exo 2}
\newfontfamily{\boldtitle}[UprightFont={* Bold}]{Exo 2}
\newfontfamily{\footerheaderfont}{Exo 2}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{CustomGray}{HTML}{909090}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {D:/[input]/letter F img} }

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\footerheaderfont\small{Author}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\footerheaderfont\small{Title}


\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\footerheaderfont\small\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\footerheaderfont\small\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
\titleformat*{\section}{\fontsize{24}{36}\boldtitle}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{12pt}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\newcommand\dictentry[3]{
    \large
    \hangindent=0cm
    \textcolor{CustomGray}{#1}\textbf{#2}: \enspace \textit{#3}
}

\tolerance=8000



\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \vspace*{3cm}
            
            \fontsize{36}{40}\selectfont
            
            \boldtitle{Aneks F:}
            
            \vspace{0.5cm}
            
            \normaltitle{Fotokorpus haseł \emph{SW}}
            
            \vfill
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}

    \setcounter{page}{202}


            \vbox{%
            
            \dictentry{}
            {Formować}
            {tom I (A-G), litera F, str. 763, kol. lewa, akapit 26 – str. 763, kol. prawa, akapit 01}

            
            \begin{mdframed}[linewidth=2pt, linecolor=CustomGray, nobreak=true]
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"page-0763, col-1, par-26 fin.png"}
            \end{mdframed}
            
            \begin{mdframed}[linewidth=2pt, linecolor=CustomGray, nobreak=true]
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"page-0763, col-2, par-01 fin.png"}
            \end{mdframed}
            
            \vspace{1em}
        }
    

\end{document}
```

It produces the following issue with text wrapping:
[image]

What I want to achieve is (✓ - achieved, ✗ - not achieved):

1. ✓ Prevent the images fromexceeding text area (page-breaking when necessary);
2. ✓ sticking images to captions (one caption sometimes has multiple images);
3. ✗ break the "caption" to break when necessary.

How do I change my code to achieve that?

======

*EDIT:*

After using `\parbox` inside `\vbox` and correcting syntactic issues outlined by @Don Housek:

```
\vbox{%
    
    \parbox{4cm}{
        \dictentry{}
        {Formować}
        {tom I (A-G), litera F, str. 763, kol. lewa, akapit 26 – str. 763, kol. prawa, akapit 01}
    }
    
    \begin{mdframed}[linewidth=2pt, linecolor=CustomGray, nobreak=true]
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"page-0763, col-1, par-26 fin.png"}
    \end{mdframed}
    
    \begin{mdframed}[linewidth=2pt, linecolor=CustomGray, nobreak=true]
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"page-0763, col-2, par-01 fin.png"}
    \end{mdframed}
    
    \vspace{1em}
}
```

It indeed started wrapping the text (fulfilling point No. 3 above), but it now produces an additional newline and thus breaks the point No. 2 about sticking the "caption" to images:
[image]

Comment: what you describe is essentially provided by the standard figure and `\caption` commands, as you do not say what issues you have it is hard to answer. If you put text on a parbox it will have an effect, but you did not show what you did. If you put a figure encironment into a vbox (or any box) you will get an error message and no output,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't understand—haven't I said specifically what I changed in a descriptive manner? What can I do to make it more understandable?

Comment: the answer to the question as written would be "use `\caption`" except that you wrote " I am not using the \caption environment, because it seems to break things"  so basically you are asking us to debug an error in the caption usage without showing any input or showing what error you got.

Comment: and your descriptions can not be right, if you put text in a `\parbox{2cm}{....}` then it will be line wrappped to 2cm (or tex will complain if it can not achieve that) so your description of simply "no effect" is not anything that gives any information about what you didm

Comment: Indeed it would help if you provide a small example of a generated LaTeX file, with just one image and one caption. The file should be complete, so with the documentclass and preamble, but otherwise as small as possible. Then we can show you how to achieve the desired output, with or without the `\caption` command. Currently it is not really possible to answer, as we don't know the code that generated your current output.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle apologies, I haven't noticed that my code didn't past the first time… fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding syntactic errors thanks to @Don Housek's suggestion, I was able to generate intended-width text with wrapping, which produced breaks between the "caption" and images. Then I simply fixed it by adding a newline suppression with `\unskip`:

```
\vbox{%

\parbox{15cm}{
    \dictentry{}
    {Formować}
    {tom I (A-G), litera F, str. 763, kol. lewa, akapit 26 – str. 763, kol. prawa, akapit 01}
}

\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=2pt, linecolor=CustomGray, nobreak=true]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"page-0763, col-1, par-26 fin.png"}
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=2pt, linecolor=CustomGray, nobreak=true]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"page-0763, col-2, par-01 fin.png"}
\end{mdframed}

\vspace{1em}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're ignoring errors in your output. `\colon` is a math mode command to get a colon without relation spacing (e.g., for typing `$f\colon X\to Y$`). Replace your `\colon` with `:` and you'll get the expected error.

Moral of the story: **DO NOT IGNORE LaTeX's ERRORS**.

Comment: I have scrutinied the error log that was produced regardless of this correction, and found that indeed I have a surplus close bracket – it works now, but it produces problem with point number 2. See my edit for details.